# Отображение картинки на Canvas

Tags: gwt, canvas, java, html5

Надо отобразить иконку на Canvas. Использую метод:

```
drawImage(image, x1, y1, w1, h1, x1, y1, w1, h1);
```

Картинка задается как ресурс:

```
public interface Bundle extends ClientBundle {
  public static final Bundle ourInstance = GWT.create(Bundle.class);

  @ClientBundle.Source(value = {"icon.png"})
  public ImageResource icon();
}
```

В момент отрисовки каринка 100% загружена (был вызван onLoad). Но всё равно картинка не рисуется, падает исключение:

> com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException:
> (INDEX_SIZE_ERR): INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM
> Exception 1   at
> com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:237)
>   at
> com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132)
>   at
> com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>   at
> com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
>   at
> com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
>   at
> MyClassCanvas.drawImage(MyClassCanvas.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените

```
Image img = new Image(Bundle.ourInstance.icon())
```

на

```
Image img = new Image(Bundle.ourInstance.icon().getURL)
```